# iso-8859-1 string to Unicode string

Tags: c#, unicode

i get html source of page with this line of code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string sPage = client.DownloadString(url);
```

page code package is  iso-8859-1

but exist unicode string like below in html source

```
<span title="&#1590;&#1575;&#1601;&#1607;"
```

how can i convert this code to Unicode string in c# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string s = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@"<span title=""&#1590;&#1575;&#1601;&#1607;");
```